# Is it possible to monitor a list (or mutable sequence) for when a member of the list is modified?

Tags: python, list, sequence, observer-pattern, mutable

Say I have a very simple data type:

```
class SimpleObject:
    def __init__(self, property):
        self.property = property

    def update_property(self, value):
        self.property = value
```

And I a special kind of list to store the data type:

```
class SimpleList(collections.MutableSequence):
    def update_useful_property_of_list(self, value):
        self.useful_property_of_list = value
```

And I store them:

```
simple1 = SimpleObject(1)
simple2 = SimpleObject(2)

simple_list = SimpleList([simple1, simple2])
```

Is there any way for the `SimpleList` object to know when one of the properties of its members changes?  For example, how can I get `simple_list` to execute `self.update_useful_property_of_list()` when something like this happens:

```
simple1.update_property(3)
```

Comment: I recall function decorators being a way to handle this. That may be a direction to look into.

Comment: It's *observer design pattern*, you can easily find sources about it with a quick search.

Comment: what do you want it to do?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've updated the question to give a simple example of what I'd like it to do.

Comment: I think  class or static methods may actually be closer to what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you are looking for the [*Observer* design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Simplest, way to do it in your example:

```
class SimpleObject:
    def __init__(self, property, propertyChangeObserver = None):
        self.property = property
        self.propertyChangeObserver = propertyChangeObserver 

    def registerPropertyChangeObserver(self, propertyChangeObserver):
        self.propertyChangeObserver = propertyChangeObserver  

    def update_property(self, value):
        self.property = value
        if self.propertyChangeObserver:
            self.propertyChangeObserver.simpleObjectPropertyChanged(self)
```

and:

```
class SimpleList(collections.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, collection):
        super(SimpleList, self).__init__(collection)
        for e in collection:
            e.registerPropertyChangeObserver(self)

    def simpleObjectPropertyChanged(self, simpleObject):
        pass # react to simpleObject.property being changed
```

Because you've called your property "property" it's hard to demonstrate low coupling here :) I've called the method `simpleObjectPropertyChanged` for clarity, but in fact, `SimpleList` doesn't have to know that it stores `SimpleObject` instances - it only needs to know that they are *observable* instances. In a similar manner, `SimpleObject` doesn't know about `SimpleList` - it only knows about some class that needs to *observe* its state (an *observer* - hence the name of the pattern).